# Maven deploy not to upload test jar

Tags: deployment, maven

We have project with lot of precanned test files, so obviously the test-jar file is very big. Since no one uses test jar(at least in out project), we don't gain any benefit by uploading it.

When we run the maven deploy command, I want it to only upload the project jar file and not the test jar file. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: It seems to me that by default my test classes are not bundled into test-jar. Do you have a specific configuration?

Comment: FYI close question to not deploy "-sources.jar" see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580969/how-do-i-exclude-the-sources-jar-in-mvn-deploy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the test jar files do not get built by default.  It is likely that you are building them explicitly using [attached tests](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html).  If so, you can remove that config from your project and you should be good to go.

Look for a section like the following and you can remove the same.

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <goals>
         <goal>test-jar</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Tests will continue to run on your project without the above.

Comment: I need the test-jar but do not want to upload to nexus. How do we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Placing your test files in `src\test\java` should have the desired results.  See [Maven directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for the convention.  You will derive the most benefit from using Maven if you follow such a project organization.  Most plugins **assume** that you have structured your project files in this manner.

Comment: We do follow this structure, we have all our test files in src\test\resources\.... That's how they become part of the test-jar.