# Installation and deployment of maven test-jar

Tags: maven, unit-testing, maven-central

I've discovered the wonderful `test-jar` facility in Maven: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html

But it may so happen that one project needs to use the test-jar of another project. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/6469256/421049 and experimentation, it would seem that using `mvn install` does not install the test-jar to the local `~/.m2/repository`. So how does one project on my machine use the test jars of another project not in the same aggregate POM?

Yet it would seem from [Maven deploy not to upload test jar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8246136/421049) that deployment of a project to Maven Central does in fact deploy the test-jar? So I can deploy it to Nexus but not install it locally? And if I deploy it to Nexus, will my local project using a dependency of `<type>test-jar</type>` go find it on Maven Central?

Comment: I'm not sure what brings you to the conclusion that the test-jar is not installed nor uploaded to a remote repository ? Apart from that the description of the link for `Maven deploy not to upload test jar` was intended to prevent uploading the test-jar to a remote repository...based on the size of the resulting jar...something different...

Comment: For more help, post your `pom.xml` first.

Comment: "I'm not sure what brings you to the conclusion that the test-jar is not installed..." I opened up my `~/.m2/repository` directory tree and I saw no test jars. But I just checked again and they are there, so I may have been looking in the wrong directory the first time. (I have several similarly-named projects.)

Comment: "...nor uploaded to a remote repository?" Actually my question indicates that I understood that it _does_ upload to a remote repository, hence my confusion at the apparent discrepancy.

Comment: You mean the discrepancy between the different post ?

Comment: No, I was confused between the apparent discrepancy of Maven not _installing_ a test-jar, but still _deploying_ it to Nexus. As I note in another comment, this may have been my mistake; if Maven does in fact install a test-jar to the local repository, and Maven also deploys a test-jar to Nexus, there is no discrepancy.

Comment: OK, now I'm more confused than ever. Somehow I had the test-jar in my local Maven repository. But my colleague was running into build problems, so I removed the test-jar from my local repository. Now my Maven project won't build anymore, and even running `mvn install` for the project won't store the test-jar in my local repository. I'll investigate further...

Comment: Hahaha! I found the source of the problem, which explains everything. See my separate answer.

Comment: And yes, @carlspring, you're right: if I would have posted the entire `pom.xml` it would have helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `maven-jar-plugin` does in fact install the test-jar (e.g. `foo-1.2.3-tests.jar`) in the local Maven repository `~/.m2/repository/...`. Wonderful!

My problem is that I had inadvertently configured the `maven-jar-plugin` to be in a separate profile named `release`. (I had copied and pasted to the wrong location in my POM.) That's why the test-jar didn't show up in my local repository after a `mvn install`, and that's why it suddenly showed up later (after I used `-P release` once in testing), and I thought I had just missed it when I looked the first time.

I move the `maven-jar-plugin` to the `<build>` section and everything is working fine: the test-jar gets put into the local maven repository using `mvn install`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was setting `maven.test.skip` for a particular build profile.  That property actually causes tests to not be compiled/installed, thus also preventing their deploy.  The solution was to set the `skipTests` property instead.