# Exported Jar is way different from debugging version

Tags: java, file, jar, export

I've finished a program (Mediaplayer) and now I'd like to export stuff. This goes without any problems, but the exported, runnable .jar file, is much bigger than the debugging version in eclipse!?

So the JFrame is bigger, the JButtons, the JSliders, the JTextfields, everything is bigger :( and it now looks quite shit...

Is there mabey any setting I must activate or do I have to test the exported version always?

Hope you can help me.

PS: There is no maven implemented in this project

Comment: I guess you are using maven. You may have enabled the 'compile with sources' option for building your project. This could be a possible reason.

Comment: Yes I am using maven... I‘ll try it thanks

Comment: I absolutely cannot find the option... Does anyone knows where such an option is? I'm running on eclipse mars.2

Comment: Read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580969/how-do-i-exclude-the-sources-jar-in-mvn-deploy . It is a matter of maven configuration.

Comment: This does not help :(. Also I tried the following: Delete Maven from Project, and run and export, but there are still the same problems...